# Using the parameters of the original method in the overriding method

Tags: java, mockito

Using Mockito, I want to override the original method with a different method, using one of the parameters of the original method. So it should look something like that:

```
Mockito.when(mock.originalMethod(someInteger)).thenAnswer(differentMethod(someInteger));
```

It should work no matter what integer is passed to the original method. It's important that the same integer passed to the original method will be used in the newMethod.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mock all calls of `originalMethod` regardless the passed integer, you can use `anyInt()`. To call the `differentMethod` you can extract the passed integer with `invocation.getArgument(..)`. In summary it could look like this:

```java
when(mock.originalMethod(anyInt())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    int theInt = invocation.getArgument(0, int.class);
    return mock.differentMethod(theInt);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) I had an error saying that the getArgument() method can't be resolved, replaced it with getArgumentAt() and now it works 

Comment: @user16076953 It looks like `getArgumentAt(..)` is only available in Mockito v1.x, so if it's possible consider to upgrade to a newer version. ;-)